# What are the possible reasons for your statement to return 'false' when you know it's true?

Tags: python, pandas

My concrete example:

```
In: list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel())) 
Out: [nan, 1.0]
```

But when I check if this is true:

```
In: list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel())) is [nan, 1.0]
Out: False
```

Anybody can help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you disagree with the interpreter, it is almost certainly right.

Comment: Your question presupposes "you know it's true" therefore your assumption is wrong. You put your understanding up against the interpreter's behaviour and your understanding was found wanting. My point is simply that it is a better starting assumption that the mistake is yours.

Comment: I may have explained myself wrong. Of course I am trying to test things I don't know. This is just a little check before I use this test a thousand times. I am trying to discriminate the unique responses of a column in pandas.

Answer (score 3):

`is` tests to see if the expressions on each side are the *same* object.  To see if they are equivalent, use `==`.

Comment: Thank you. What I am actually trying to test is if the output `[nan, 1.0]` is inside a set, which if by construction I know it is true, it still returns as false. That is why I needed to check if it was the same object rather than checking if it was equivalent. Should I re-formulate the question?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by testing if the output is inside a set, but if you use `is` there, it is impossible for it ever to evaluate to `True`, because you are creating a new list for the comparison.

Comment: My set would be `s=[[nan,1.0],[0,1]]` and I would like to test if the output of `list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel()))`, which I know it's `[nan, 1.0]`, is inside `s`, which I also know it's true. So, would the correct syntax be `list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel()))  in s`? The output I get from this is `False` but I am quite sure I am doing everything wrong here after readin the posts. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Either way, even if you were to properly use ==, you'd still get `False`. A quick workaround would be to filter out nan's:

```
[x for x in list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel())) if str(x) != 'nan'] == ...
```

See why ["NaN" doesn't equal "NaN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values).

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need test like:

```
In [73]: df['x']
Out[73]: 
0    np.nan
1         1
Name: x, dtype: object

In [74]: list(pd.unique(df['x'].ravel())) == ['np.nan', '1']
Out[74]: True
```